# Regex match only first row after specified word

Tags: regex

I'd like to get the authors of a book from the list below with regular expression.

```
Title:
Jackalope Springs Eternal
Authors:
Shannon Watters,  Noelle Stevenson, Brooklyn Allen
Genre:
Fantasy
```

So I just want to get the names under `Authors:` These are: `Shannon Watters, Noelle Stevenson, Brooklyn Allen`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple pattern will do the job:

```
Authors:\n(.*)
```

[**Online demo**](https://pythex.org/?regex=Authors%3A%5Cn(.*)&test_string=Title%3A%0AJackalope%20Springs%20Eternal%0AAuthors%3A%0AShannon%20Watters%2C%20%20Noelle%20Stevenson%2C%20Brooklyn%20Allen%0AGenre%3A%0AFantasy&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Thanks, could you rewrite this into #C?

Comment: @SchalkMátyás It is the same in C#

Comment: @SchalMátyás This pattern will work for almost every regex engine, also C#'s one.